# Xamarin forms pcl has stopped building

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin.forms

The project has been building Ok for a long time, and now it has stoped building with the error below

There was a mismatch between the processor architecture of the project being built "MSIL" and the processor architecture of the reference "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\mscorlib.dll", "x86".

The project is targetting .Net Framework 4.5, so I am confused about the 4.0 in the referenced dll.

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: What did you change?

Comment: I did not change anything. A Windows 10 update was installed and somehow Drive C and D got swapped. After sorting out the drives my I reloaded the project and it no longer worked. I checked out a slightly older version which was building and it no longer builds eiter.